# Get AD Guid from HttpContext.Current.User

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory

I have tried many, many different ways, to get this data. But I can't get it to work.
I have a MVC4 application, hooked up with Active Directory. But I need the users AD GUID.

I tried:

```
(Guid)Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey;
WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
```

But none of them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it (Not pretty...):

```
string login = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;            
string domain = login.Substring(0, login.IndexOf('\\'));
string userName = login.Substring(login.IndexOf('\\') + 1);
DirectoryEntry domainEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain);
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(domainEntry);
searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))",userName);
SearchResult searchResult = searcher.FindOne();
DirectoryEntry entry = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
Guid objectGuid = entry.Guid;
```

The original code used : `entry.NativeGuid`, but I changed because of Little / Big endian "problems"

`entry.Guid` has the same "format" as in AD.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
   // find a user
   UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, User.Identity.Name);

   if(user != null)
   {
      Guid userGuid = user.Guid ?? Guid.Empty;
   }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. I'm on .NET 4